# Wordpress me vuelve a saltar el instalador

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Debido a un error con el servidor xampp (al activar mysql), he tenifo que borrar los archivos de la carpeta C:xammp/mysql/data. Ahora cuando abro la ruta del dashboard de wordpress me vuelve a salir el instalador. Como puedo volver al estado de antes. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Lexahabla si has borrado esa carpeta, has borrado los archivos de la base de datos, por lo que si quieres que vuelva a aparecer tu dashboard tendrás que volver a poner los archivos en esa carpeta (con suerte no los has borrado de la papelera de reciclaje). Si no, tendrás que reinstalar XAMP y volver a crear la instalación de wordpress (evidentemente no tendrás lo que tenías antes, básicamente porque los has borrado).